# How to Identify Parent Quantity in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Any assistance you can provide would be amazing.

I have a query that pulls in three values: sort order, level and quantity

What I need is a fourth column that shows the quantity of the parent level.  So if the level is '3', I need the quantity of the parent above it that is level '2'.  The levels can vary, which is why this is tricky.

The following is the SQL statement for the Oracle database and the image shows the expected results if the fourth column was there for parent quantity:

```
select end_part_id, sort_order, level, comp_qty
from report_table
order by sort_order
```

[image: Sample Table]

Comment: You need a recursive hierarchical query, but the exact answer is highly database-specific.  So, you should tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm using Oracle 10.2 and my query tool is Golden 5.7.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you don't need a recursive query, `lag()` should do for this

Comment: @DavidL You should show the original data as well, as this might be necessary to give you an exact query.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?  I've been trying the lag function, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Wow a 15 years old Oracle release. You may consider an upgrade.

Comment: @DavidL: I have posted an answer below, just take a hit... All the best!!!

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  Got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the parant quantity by looking up the last value in the records with a lower `sort_order` and lower `Level`:

```
select sort_order, level, comp_qty,
  (
    select max(comp_qty) keep (dense_rank last order by sort_order)
    from report_table parent_record
    where parent_record.sort_order < report_table.sort_order
      and parent_record.level      < report_table.level
  ) as parent_qty
from report_table
order by sort_order;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to provide a solution without any test data (and I am not going to generate them by myself) but I assume this expression should work:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COMP_QTY ORDER BY "LEVEL" RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Note, `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default, so you can skip it. I put it just for sake of clarity. `LEVEL` is a reserved word for hierarchical queries, thus you should use a different alias/column name or enclose it by quotes.

Comment: Thanks!  Funny comment about my Oracle version.  It's what they gave me...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, it is some tricky but it gives your desired result:

SQL:

```
select sort_order,lvl,comp_qty,
    (select distinct first_value(comp_qty) over(order by sort_order desc,lvl desc)
    from report_table
    where sort_order <x.sort_order
    and lvl<x.lvl) PARENT_QTY
from report_table x
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b106d/52)

Comment: KKK, Thanks for the help.  I've been trying to get your query to work, but the one twist is that the 'Level' field is actually built where there is a space in front of the level.  For example level 1 = '1' and level 2 = ' 2' (one space) and level 3 = '  3' (two spaces).  I've updated your demo so the level has spaces.  Can you please take a look?

Comment: Not yet.  One last thing.  There is also an 'END_PART_ID' that is on the table that needs to be joined as well.  I should have included that in the original SQL statement.  The SQL should be select end_part_id, sort_order, level, comp_qty from report_table order by sort_order

Comment: And next time, you must put all your requirement in single shot, because its not your customer support nor free code service. everyone has their importance of time. so better think to put all your requirement in one go.... Keep in mind

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

This was the final statement that got it working.  Thanks again for your help!

```
(select end_part_id, sort_order, indented_lvl, comp_qty,
(select distinct first_value(i.comp_qty) over(order by i.sort_order desc,
TRIM(i.indented_lvl) desc)
from report_table i
where i.end_part_id = x.end_part_id
and i.sort_order < x.sort_order
and TRIM(i.level) < TRIM(x.level)) as "PARENT_QTY"
from report_table x
where x.end_part_id = 'XX')
```

Comment: As this is exactly KKK's solution (only adjusted to your real database with columns unknown to us), you should accept their answer.

Comment: This was my first post.  I believe I did by checking the check mark next to his answer.  Is there something else I need to do?  Thanks!

Comment: No, that's it. You can, however, always upvote answers you find useful. This includes the accepted one. I don't know, if you are allowed to, yet, though. Maybe you need more points for this.